# Running Multi Query but I have one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to Insert a lot of data but mysql query doesnt work it. Result Only one row I Cant see more rows

```
function addSeri($seriName,$name,$piece,$price,$seri_end_date)
{
    include 'connect.php';
    $dd=explode("/",$seri_end_date);
    $seri_end_date=$dd['2'].'-'.$dd['1'].'-'.$dd['0'];
    echo $seri_end_date;
    for ($i=1;$i<$piece;$i++)
    {
        echo $i;
        $veri[$price];
        $ticketNo= strtoupper(substr(md5(microtime()),0,10)).strtoupper(substr(md5(substr(string, start)), 0, 5));

        $seriAdd=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tickets(ticket_no,ticket_seri,ticket_end_date,ticket_status) VALUES ('$ticket_no', '$seriName', '$seri_end_date', 0)");           
    }       
}
```

Comment: You don't provide enough information, so there are too many possibilities.  Perhaps `$piece = 1`.  My best guess would be a unique constraint of some sort on the table.  You should check for errors when you run SQL queries.  You should also stop using "mysql_".  And, use parameterized queries.

Comment: $piece = 12; but Query is running at first but not continue

Comment: thanks :) I solved , table one column was unique I changed it and run query

Comment: Like Gordon said, parameterised queries are safer. If your `$seriName` contains a `'` like in `"O'Connell"` and you have not masked it adequately the `Insert` statement will fail.

Comment: The language you are calling from is also important - some have an ability to append records to a local dataset and then 'insert' the dataset to the database which is usually a lot faster